# Sign APK same as AAB

Tags: android, bundle, sign

How can I sign my APK same as AAB (android app bundle)?

I have 2 problem

1- I want to use sms-retriever and want has same hash string for both APK and AAB
2- I upload my add in google play and unofficial android app stores , In google pplay I upload AAB file , and as the unofficial store cannot support AAB I upload universal APK  , the problem is If someone download app from play store , they cannot update it form unofficial android app stores and vise versa , because the sign is different

Comment: You can sign it with the same key wether you generate it through APK or AAB.

Comment: In play store, do not use app signing, then your app on play store and unofficial store will be sign as the same key.

Comment: @jake Your approach didn't works , Can you explain more?

Comment: @TuanLuong I want to send AAB to google play :-)

Comment: Yes, you still need to sign to upload to play store. But do not enable App Signing in google play https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play. Because if you enable it, google will sign you app again with a difference key

Comment: @TuanLuong Can you explain how exactly I can disable app signing? any screen shot?

Comment: I added a screenshot below

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your app are using `App Signing` by accessing Release management > App signing. If you opted in, you can not disable it.

```
Note: Opting in to app signing by Google Play applies for the lifetime of your app
```

[image]

Comment: I never opted in , So it is disabled? if yes why signing is different ?

Comment: Yes. So the key must be the same. Could you try to install the apk loccally while having play store version installed

Comment: No , I cannot install